# Split a string not knowing its length without using split()

Tags: java, split

> We don't know the string length until the user enters it but the input format is like number-number-number...
> The numbers don't have the same number of digits.
> Consider this input
> 10000-20-150-2-12345-2-1-450000-30-2-50

I'm only allowed to use Scanner(System.in) and save this in a string but not allowed to use parseInt or Integer.valueOf or toCharArray or arrays or split function to extract the numbers into an array.
How can I make a split function and use it?
I thought about for loop and charAt(i)=='-' though but I don't know how to get the numbers.

Comment: Did you try anything yet?  Are you familiar with any of the methods of String?

Comment: Hint: A Scanner uses a delimiter, which is whitespace by default, to determine the how to read in input in many of its method to read in input. You can set a Scanners [delimiter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.lang.String-) to anything you want (including `"-"`).

Comment: Are you allowed to use `Character.isDigit(char c)`?

Comment: Is the number of hyphens ("`-`") always the same?

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse a string into a int, you can use :

```java
// Parse string to int without using Integer.parseInt() or Integer.valueOf()
public static int stringToInteger(String str) {
    int answer = 0, factor = 1;
    for (int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        answer += (str.charAt(i) - '0') * factor;  // '0' is to get the ascii code of 0
        factor *= 10;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

In your processing code :

- You can know the result array length with (java 8) :

```java
int[] result = new int[userInput.chars().filter(ch -> ch == '-').count() + 1];
```

- And you just have to iterate over the userInput String using `charAt(n)`  method and stock the char in a StringBuilder until you get a "-", and then call the stringToInteger method to add the int in the array :

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int resultIndex = 0;
char c;
for(int i=0 ; i< userInput.length(); i++) {
    char c = userInput.charAt(i);
    if(c == '-') {
        result[resultIndex++] = stringToInteger(sb.toString());
        sb.setLength(0); // Empty the stringBuilder
    }
    else {
        sb.append(c); // Add char in the stringBuilder
    }
}
```

Comment: How can u use charAt when many of the numbers in the string have more than one digit

Comment: I'm not allowed to use arrays or lists or other java data structures. Should I make a data structure myself?

Comment: If the userInput String is "147-....",  you add '1' in the string builder (i=0), then you add '4' (i=1) so stringbuilder is now equals to "14", then you add '7' (i=2) so the stringBuilder is equals to 147. When i=3, the char is '-' so you parse your stringBuilder (ie. "147") into int and save 147 in the array. And so on ... So you have to stock an array of int without using array ? It's weird  So store "147-23-....." in a string (the userInput) and custom your method so it takes a parameter index, for example getInt(0) which return 147, getInt(1) which return 23... by parsing the string

Comment: For exemple, you can create a class `MyData` with a String attribute, and a method `getInt(int index)` which can process the String so you can call : `MyData data = new MyData("156-28-26-381") ; data.getInt(0) // return 156 ; data.getInt(2) // return 26 ; data.getInt(4) // throw an arror`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using nothing fancy, just `String.charAt()`:

```
String input = "10000-20-150-2-12345-2-1-450000-30-2-50";
String curValue = "";
for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
  char c = input.charAt(i);
  if (!(c == '-')) {
    curValue = curValue + c;
  }
  else {
    // ... do something with curValue ...
    System.out.println(curValue);

    // reset curValue
    curValue = "";
  }
}
if (curValue.length() > 0) {
  // ... do something with curValue ...
  System.out.println(curValue);
}
```

We just iterate over the characters and accumulate them in "curValue" until you hit a dash.  Then you process what is in "curValue" and reset it back to a blank string.  After iterating all characters you need to process the last value left in "curValue".